# method to change type of role classes in JS

Tags: javascript, class, methods, task

So i have a task with classes in javascript,and i should have an Admin type with a constructor and two methods,one to getArray which return an array of guests and users,and a method changeType which gets a number (the array index) modifies the array item at the provided index (changes the object type from a guest to a user and otherwise and as a result, the tasks should migrated from one type to another), and returns a modified array of items.

To be more clear about my task,here is the full description :

[image: Task description]

And this is the example of implementation:

```
 const guest = new Guest(
      [
        new Task('task name 1'),
        new Task('task name 2'),
        new Task('task name 3'),
      ]
    );
    
    guest.getTask(0) // { name: 'task name 1' }
    guest.getTask(2) // { name: 'task name 3' }
    guest.createTask(new Task('task name 4')) // taskName is not defined, should not work
    
const user = new User(
  [
    new Task('task name 1'),
    new Task('task name 2'),
    new Task('task name 3'),
  ]
);

user.getTask(0) // { name: 'task name 1' }
user.getTask(2) // { name: 'task name 3' }
user.createTask(new Task('task name 4'))
user.getTask(3) // {name: 'task name 4'}

const admin = new Admin(
  [
    new Guest([]),
    new Guest([new Task('task name 1')]),
    new User([]),
    new User([new Task('task name 2')]),
  ]
);

admin.getArray(); // [Guest, Guest, User, User]
admin.changeType(1);
admin.getArray(); // [Guest, User, User, User]
```

I dont have a problem with the rest of the task,my problem is at **changeType** method.It gives me somehow the expected result in browser,but then when i test it with npm it says that *Admin should change type of role from User to Guest* .
Here is my implementation :

```
class Admin {
    constructor(userGuestArray) {
        this.userGuestArray = userGuestArray;
    }
    getArray() {
        return this.userGuestArray;
    }

    changeType(index, replace, arr) {
        replace = this.userGuestArray;
        arr = this.userGuestArray[index];
        if (replace[index] = Guest) {
            replace[index] = new User(arr.tasks);

        } else {
            replace[index] = new Guest(arr.tasks);
        }
        return replace;
    }
}
```

And here is the test:

```
describe('Admin', () => {
    let admin;
    beforeEach(() => {
        admin = new Admin([
              new Guest([]),
              new Guest([new Task('task name 1')]),
              new User([]),
              new User([new Task('task name 2')]),
        ]);
    })
    it('should have method getArray', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray().length).to.equal(4);
    });
    it('should return instance of Guest as a first element by the method getArray', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[0]).to.deep.equal({ tasks: []});
    });
    it('should return instance of User as a third element by the method getArray', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[3]).to.deep.equal({ tasks: [{ name: 'task name 2'}]});
    });
    it('should return array of roles by the method getArray', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()).to.deep.equal([{ tasks: []}, { tasks: [{ name: 'task name 1'}]}, { tasks: []}, { tasks: [{ name: 'task name 2'}]}]);
    });
    it('should change type of role from Guest to User', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[0] instanceof Guest).to.equal(true);
        admin.changeType(0);
        expect(admin.getArray()[0] instanceof User).to.equal(true);
    });

    it('should change type of role from User to Guest', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[3] instanceof User).to.equal(true);
        admin.changeType(3);
        expect(admin.getArray()[3] instanceof Guest).to.equal(true);
    });

    it('should move tasks from Guest to User, when change role', () => {
        expect(admin.getArray()[1].getTask(0)).to.deep.equal({ name: 'task name 1'});
        admin.changeType(1);
        expect(admin.getArray()[1].getTask(0)).to.deep.equal({ name: 'task name 1'});
    });
});
```

Could you guys help me to fix this method please? It's the last thing i should do to submit the task but i have no ideas how to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if (replace[index] = Guest) {` is a mistake, that overwrites the array element with the `Guest` function.

Comment: Btw, also don't forget to declare your local variables `replace` and `arr` with `const` or `let`

Comment: And how should i check then when somebody input the index,for example 3,and on the index 3 there is a Guest with task name 1 and i should replace Guest to User that have the same task name as Guest?in few words,to change only the class name :\ It seems to be an ultra hardcore task 4 me

Comment: Your approach with the if statements and the creation of new instances is fine. Only the check is wrong: how do you test whether an object is an instance of a class? It's not `=`.

Comment: with instanceof

Comment: Exactly. So fix your line and it should work!

Comment: Woooooooooow,it works,you have put such a good question,thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,after reading the comments and searching for documentations,i rewrote the function and get it working.

```
changeType(index) {
       let mainArray = this.userGuestArray;
       let arr = this.userGuestArray[index];
        if (mainArray[index] instanceof Guest) {
            mainArray[index] = new User(arr.tasks);

        } else if (mainArray[index] instanceof User) {
            mainArray[index] = new Guest(arr.tasks);
        }
        return mainArray;
    }
```